# Customise default treeNetwork to collapse and include nodeID

Tags: r, networkd3

A couple of questions relating to [treeNetwork](https://rdrr.io/github/christophergandrud/networkD3/man/treeNetwork.html).

Is it possible to set the treeNetwork from networkD3 to be collapsed by default?
My hierarchy tree has 6 levels to it, so I would prefer not to show all of the branches initially.

I would also like to show the `nodeID` name on each node but cannot see the option for this. Is it possible?

Finally, maybe more complex but is it possible to click a node at a lower level and have the tree restructure so that level becomes the new root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the treeNetwork from networkD3 to be collapsed by default?

no

> is it possible to click a node at a lower level and have the tree restructure so that level becomes the new root?

no

> I would also like to show the nodeID name on each node but cannot see the option for this. Is it possible?

this is the default behaviour...

```r
# devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
library(networkD3)

tree <- read.csv(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
nodeId,parentId,name
1,,one
2,1,two
3,1,three
4,2,four
5,2,five
6,3,six
7,3,seven
")

treeNetwork(tree)
```

[image]